# How to ensure downloaded documents/files can only be accessed from my Windows 8.1 Store app?

Tags: security, windows-store-apps, sandbox

I am developing a new app that target Windows 8 upwards. It generates and downloads sensitive documents which should only be accessible from the app after logging in.

Since the Windows filesystem is open to Explorer, is there a way to only allow access through my app?

I have already read a bunch of blog posts that talk about how the app is limited in a sandbox so that it can't affect the wider OS, however none have discussed having a secure directory that is not accessible from outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

As a first note, if you allow users to download data to devices they control, and your program can access it, they will be able to access it. In your context, you would want to worry less about benign users accessing it, and worry more about malware and malicious users. With that in mind, you have two goals:

1. Restrict access to files such that only my application can access them
2. Restrict access such that my application only has access when the intended user is using it.

There are likely several viable methods of attaining those goals; but as a crypto geek, I of course recommend cryptography. In brief, you can use cryptography to attain these goals in this manner:

1. When your program initiates, have it generate a random key and store it in an accessible location on disk. Before storing it, use some user-specific secret (like their password) to encrypt the key itself.
2. When a user downloads a file, encrypt it with the key you have stored. When a user accesses a file, decrypt it with the aforementioned key.

This ensures that the plaintext of the documents is never stored on disk, only in memory, and that an attacker cannot simply steal the key along with the documents. Note that, however, the plaintext key and documents will exist in memory, and a sufficiently sophisticated attacker could be able to retrieve them if they had access to the system while a legitimate user was using your program.